# Calculating Win-rates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to calculate win-rates of the players from a table (bots_match_history) which has data in the format:

```
id  |    username     | sub_level_id | bot_type | match_result | system_win_balance |         created_at         | analyzed | stakes 
------+-----------------+--------------+----------+--------------+--------------------+----------------------------+----------+--------
 5487 | ashishish       |            5 | hard     | l            |               -831 | 2017-11-29 06:26:13.288267 | f        |     18
 5486 | dilip.kumar     |            3 | hard     | l            |               -821 | 2017-11-29 06:25:09.106075 | f        |     50
 5485 | abhinav.garg    |            5 | hard     | w            |               -791 | 2017-11-29 06:24:07.589281 | f        |     18
```

I need to use only those entries which haven't been analyzed yet (analyzed=false) and which has more than 3 entries for a particular level.

This is the query that I had written, somehow for some entries it is returning a win-rate of > 100%.

```
WITH total AS (
    SELECT COUNT(b.match_result) AS total_matches, b.bot_type, sl.level_id, b.stakes
    FROM bots_match_history b
    JOIN sub_levels sl ON b.sub_level_id = sl.id
    WHERE b.analyzed=FALSE 
    GROUP BY b.bot_type, sl.level_id, b.stakes
    HAVING COUNT(b.match_result) >=3
)
SELECT total.bot_type, total.level_id, total.stakes, round(cast(((
        SELECT COUNT(b2.*)
        FROM bots_match_history b2
          JOIN sub_levels sl2 ON b2.sub_level_id = sl2.id
        WHERE b2.match_result='w' AND b2.analyzed=FALSE
            AND b2.bot_type = total.bot_type AND sl2.level_id = total.level_id
    )::FLOAT * 100.0 / total.total_matches) AS NUMERIC), 2)::FLOAT AS win_percentage
FROM total, bots_match_history b3
JOIN sub_levels sl3 ON sl3.id = b3.sub_level_id
WHERE b3.bot_type = total.bot_type AND sl3.level_id=total.level_id
GROUP BY total.bot_type, total.level_id, total.stakes, total.total_matches;
```

What is wrong in this query that it is returning a win-rate of more than 100%?

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(b.match_result) >=3` limits total to be less...

Comment: I wanted to get entries with minimum count 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping your total by `stakes`, but do not JOIN by it later, so one row from total (limited to certain stakes) can be matched with more rows than calculating total did (depends on how many of those are won).

I have made fiddle, excluding `sub_levels` table and substituting it with `sub_level_id` instead for grouping and joins: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b3558b9d3cddc63a47d3f29a4a6c08f6

Fixed SQL should look like this:

```
WITH total AS (
    SELECT COUNT(b.match_result) AS total_matches, b.bot_type, sl.level_id, b.stakes
    FROM bots_match_history b
    JOIN sub_levels sl ON b.sub_level_id = sl.id
    WHERE b.analyzed=FALSE 
    GROUP BY b.bot_type, sl.level_id, b.stakes
    HAVING COUNT(b.match_result) >=3
)
SELECT total.bot_type, total.level_id, total.stakes, round(cast(((
        SELECT COUNT(b2.*)
        FROM bots_match_history b2
          JOIN sub_levels sl2 ON b2.sub_level_id = sl2.id
        WHERE b2.match_result='w' AND b2.analyzed=FALSE
            AND b2.bot_type = total.bot_type AND sl2.level_id = total.level_id
            AND b2.stakes = total.stakes
    )::FLOAT * 100.0 / total.total_matches) AS NUMERIC), 2)::FLOAT AS win_percentage
FROM total, bots_match_history b3
JOIN sub_levels sl3 ON sl3.id = b3.sub_level_id
WHERE b3.bot_type = total.bot_type AND sl3.level_id=total.level_id
  AND b3.stakes=total.stakes
GROUP BY total.bot_type, total.level_id, total.stakes, total.total_matches;
```

Also, you might get (IMO) incorrect results if you limit yourself to analyzed rows only. I saw 40% winrate for one set of parameters, then checked actual rows and there was actually 3 won and 3 lost games with left me puzzled for a while only to notice that one of those won games was "analyzed" already.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the mistake indeed. But I am running this query every 30mins to get some calibrations. For this, I don't want to use the rows which were already considered in the previous run.